# Shows me android:src error

Tags: android

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher'). Why do I get this error?

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to specify the specific folder. It is the system that loads the correct one depending on the screen-density where your application runs

```
  android:src="@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher"
```

should be

```
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

android:src="@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher"

with

android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Don't mention the specific folder